# How to connect API gateway built in golang with microservice built in .NET

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, api-gateway

I am working on project where API gateway is built used golang and I am building 2 microservices in .NET. API gateway is exposing REST api and should translate it to gRPC (all microservices should commmunicate using gRPC). I copied my proto files which I used in .NET project to generate service to gateway but I don't know what to do next, thanks for answer in advance.

[Gateway project](https://github.com/XWS-SmFoYcSNaQ/batistuta-booking/tree/develop/api-gateway)

.proto file which I use in .NET project to generate service (it's not implemented yet just 1 dummy method)

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "user_service";

package user;

// The user service definition.
service UserService {
  rpc GetUser (US_Request) returns (US_Response);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message US_Request {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message US_Response {
  string message = 1;
}
```